# php - number of elements and bind variable mismatch

Tags: php

I seem to be getting an error message of the number of elements in type definition string not matching the number of bind variables.

```
<?php

function addToTable($data){

    $columns = array_keys($data);
    $keys = implode(", ", $columns);
    $info = array_values($data);
    $values = implode(", ", $info);

    $preholder = [];
    foreach($data as $count){
        array_push($preholder,"?");
    }
    $placeholder = implode(", ", $preholder);

    $sql = "INSERT INTO guest ($keys) VALUES ($placeholder)";
    $types = [];
    foreach($data as $x=>$y){
        if(is_numeric($y)){
            array_push($types,"i");
        }
        elseif(gettype($y) == "string"){
            array_push($types,"s");
        }
    }   
    $types = implode("",$types);

    $statement = mysqli_prepare($conn, $sql);
    mysqli_stmt_bind_param($statement, '$types', $values);
    $results = mysqli_stmt_execute($statement); 

    mysqli_close($conn);
    return $results;
}

?>
```

The only possible thing i can think of is in the bind function is actually wanting a number of values after the $type instead of an variable with the listing of values. I would like to keep this working in a way that don't have to manually change it every time.

Comment: do the following: before the code `$sql = ...`, write the following code: `foreach ($keys as $value){echo $value."<br>";} foreach ($placeholder as $value){echo $value."<br>";}` and then post the output in your Question. You might find that you have more values in one array than the other. Also, comment out all the code after you paste that, this is meant to help you debug what the issue is.

Comment: its definitely nothing wrong with the amounts. Im getting ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ? for the $placeholder, ssssssi for the bind types and tom, e, jones, 1-565-562-8764, timjones@gmail.com, new guy, 1 as some test values. On all accounts there are exactly 7